# Поставление процессов в очередь - java

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь

Мне нужно сделать на java, что бы можно было ставить процессы в очередь и они поочерёдно выполнялись.

Типо:
Один процесс мониторит за очередью, если очередь неравна 0, то он запускает процессы из данной очереди

Как правильно это реализовать, просто я пытался и а то у меня ничего не работает

Очередь:

```java
Queue<Thread> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

Процесс мониторящий за очередью:

```java
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (queue.size() != 0) {
                        Thread th = queue.peek();
                        queue.remove();
                        th.start();
                        try {
                            th.join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Функция по добавлению процессов в очередь:

```java
private void sendToDevice(final String string) {
        queue.add(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    outStream.write(string.getBytes());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }));
    }
```

Comment: а обязательно нужно вручную? потому что можно использовать         `ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` и посылать таски на выполнения. Под капотом таски будут по очереди обрабатываться. Если нужно вручную, то смотрите `LinkedBlockingQueue`

Comment: @IR42 типо процессы будут запускаться по очереди, типо один запущен а следующий ждёт?

Comment: @IR42 спс, работает

Comment: @IR42 напишите это как правильный пароль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```java
ExecutorService service1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
service1.execute(new Runnable() {
  //и здесь твой код
});
```

[статья](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/114046/)